# Why a pending intent does not start an activity when called form a service's notification

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-notifications

On my Github acccount I made a simple projet that delineate my problem [here my project](https://github.com/javaskater/NotificationService)

My Main Activity has a button whose onClick method calls a Background Service.
The Backgroundservice wait for 5 second and then fires a notification.

here the code of the BackgroundService (you can find on [Github](https://github.com/javaskater/NotificationService)

```java
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {//methode appelée en arrière plan
        if (intent != null) {

            try{
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mNotificationsManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            CharSequence tickerText = "view hike";
            Intent intentReceiverAcctivity = new Intent(TAG_INTENT);
            intentReceiverAcctivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, intentReceiverAcctivity, 0);

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

            builder.setAutoCancel(false);
            builder.setTicker(tickerText);
            builder.setContentTitle("The Hike");
            builder.setContentText("HikeMap is available");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.explore);
            Bitmap large_icon_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_action_map);
            builder.setLargeIcon(large_icon_bmp);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setOngoing(true);
            builder.setSubText("Click on this icon to access the Hike's map");   //API level 16
            builder.setNumber(5000); //durée d'apparition de l'icone dans la barre de notifications ?
            builder.build();

            Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
            mNotificationsManager.notify(11, notification);

        }
    }
```

Expanding the notification bar and clicking on the large_icon shoud start a second Activity called *ReceiverActivity* whose sole purpose is to show a different message.

On an emulator the small icon appears on the notification bar, when I expand that bar I can see the large Icon, but clicking on it does not fire the ReceiverActivity

On my smartphone no small icon on the notification bar, no large icon on the expanded notification area ...

Any Idea of what went wrong with the service code ?
The entire code of that small example is to be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/javaskater/NotificationService)...

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Intent intentReceiverAcctivity = new Intent(TAG_INTENT);

```
public final static String TAG_INTENT = "NotificationClicked";
```

Sorry, you didn't set an activity to run. You should use an Intent with two parameters like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Context, YourActivity.class);
```

Here's example of `NotificationChannel`

```
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "channel_id",
                "channel_name",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        channel.setDescription("channel_description");
        channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel_id");
    } else {
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    }
```

Comment: yes setting an activity to run makes it work on the emulator, but nothing happens on a real device when I push the click Button, no notfication at all

Comment: Which api do you test? Api >= 26 need to set `NotificationChannel` to the notification.

Comment: My Smartphone runs on API 28 (Android 9), the emulator only API19 .
Could you give me an example on how to set the notification Channel ?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed [that android developper video](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) and arrived at an the same result. But I will take your edit as a base!!!